# Access xml object

Tags: php, xml, api

I'm using YouTube API. I got following result from API :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => alternate
            [href] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blabla
        )

)
```

I'm confuse with this object. I want to access `@attributes`. How can i do it?

Comment: var_dump($xml->{'@attributes'}); $xml is your variable where u save xml

Comment: can't you just google this? [`php simplexml get attributes`](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20simplexml%20get%20attribute)

Comment: @Ghost i got this $xml->attributes()->href. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Engineer: and what about this $xml->{'@attributes'}->href ?

Comment: It should be something like this `$xml->attributes['href']` because attributes is an array

Comment: @devpro I tried `$xml->{'@attributes'}` but it returns null object.

Comment: @Tommy It does not help.

Comment: You could loop the xml this way `foreach ($xml->children() as $c)
{
    echo $c['href'];
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@attributes` part of the print_r output are just the element's attributes which can be accessed via `$obj['attrname']`.

```
<?php
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo rel="alternate" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blabla" />');
print_r($obj); // to verify that the sample data fits your actual data

echo $obj['rel'], ' | ', $obj['href'];
```

[prints](https://3v4l.org/Fr96j)

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => alternate
            [href] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blabla
        )

)
alternate | http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blabla
```

see also [Example #5 Using attributes](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-6044) in the SimpleXML documentation.